# Choice of tense and meaning in "My friend considered going to an event where X came (had come?)"

Tags: tense, backshifting, past-vs-past-perfect

My friend considered going to an event to see X.
Now if I wanted to convey a similar meaning, which of the sentences below would you suggest I use? And what's the difference between the two?

My friend considered going to an event where X **had come**.

My friend considered going to an event where X **came**.

Comment: I would not use *come*, which is vague and sounds strange to me. Maybe *attended* or *appeared* (like *see* as you mentioned).

Comment: I agree with user3169. The example sentences supplied in the question are not idiomatic, if by "come" you mean "performed" or "gave a talk", as I gather you do with the phrase "to see X".

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use either the past simple or the past perfect, with the only difference that you use the latter to give emphasis to the event happened earlier to another in the past. In this situation, X's coming is the event happened first.

Answer (score -1):

The idiomatic way to say this is to use the continuous:

> My friend considered going to an event where X *was appearing*.